# Using Sessions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show feedback from a table in mysql database that the tutor has provided but from a student logged in.

This is a project for tutors and students to use and to upload work, I've tried switching the tutor session and student session about but it wont collect the right tutorid

[Image of code provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR0Kt.png)

I would like to correct id of the tutor to present the feedback on a table when the student is logged in

Comment: Sorry, [we can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: also, you know you have a die in the script right?

Answer (score 0):

You need session_start() at the beginning of you page to use session globals.

```
<?php
session_start();
```